# Reverse-proxy under a load balancer

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, load-balancer

I am trying to build a web server using nginx. It is published to the internet under a load balancer.

It has a shared public IP (e.g. `96.1.2.3`) with a public DNS as well (e.g. `example.domain.com`). When I type in `example.domain.com` in a browser, the load balancer will do the work on reaching the real server.

Now, on the real server. I have an nginx and container that runs an application on port `1234`. I configured the nginx that it should redirect to `example.domain.com:1234` when the site is reached but it is not happening. I know the configuration is fine because running `curl -k https://example.domain.com` shows it is redirecting but when trying it in a browser, it just says the site can't be reached and that `example.domain.com` unexpectedly closed.

Is there someone that had an experiencing on making this work?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the redirection on the load balancer. Instead of directing it to port 443 of the back end server, it was directed to port 1234 and it load the site successfully.

Essentially, the initial config of reverse proxy (load balancer) to reverse proxy (nginx) did not work.